# Hacer formulario de registro incluyendo grupos de permisos

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

Hola estoy haciendo una app en django y necesito crear un formulario para el registro de los usuarios pero a la vez dentro de ese formulario darle los permisos que van a tener.

Estos permisos ya los tengo agrupados en grupos de permisos desde el admin de django.

Acá dejo el código porque hasta ahora solo puedo mostrar el registro de los usuarios pero no se como incluir la lista de grupo de permisos

Archivo `forms.py`:

```
class RegistrarUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email','groups']
        labels = {
            'username': 'Nombre de Usuario',
            'first_name': 'Primer Apellido',
            'last_name': 'Segundo Apellido',
            'email': 'Correo electrónico',
        }
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'Ingrese el nombre de usuario',
                    'id': 'username',
                }
            ),
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'Ingrese el primer apellido',
                    'id': 'first_name',
                }
            ),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'Ingrese el segundo apellido',
                    'id': 'last_name',
                }
            ),
            'email': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'Ingrese el correo electrónico',
                    'id': 'email',
                }
            ),
        }
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
class RegistrarUsuario(CreateView):
    template_name = 'Gestionpaqueteria/usuarios/crear_usuarios.html'
    form_class = RegistrarUserForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

Archivo 'crear_usuario.html'

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block contenido %}
    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% if error %}
        <h2>{{ error }}</h2>
      {% else %}
          <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                  <strong>Formulario de Registro</strong>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body card-block">
                  <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
                      <div class="row form-group">
                          <div class="col col-md-2">{{ form.username.label }}</div>
                          <div class="col-12 col-md-3">{{ form.username }}</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row form-group">
                          <div class="col col-md-2">{{ form.first_name.label }}</div>
                          <div class="col-12 col-md-3">{{ form.first_name }}</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row form-group">
                          <div class="col col-md-2">{{ form.last_name.label }}</div>
                          <div class="col-12 col-md-3">{{ form.last_name }}</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row form-group">
                          <div class="col col-md-2">{{ form.email.label }}</div>
                          <div class="col-12 col-md-3">{{ form.email }}</div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="row form-group">
                          <div class="col col-md-2"><label>Contraseña</label></div>
                          <div class="col-12 col-md-3"><input class="form-control" type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Ingrese contraseña"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row form-group">
                          <div class="col col-md-2"><label>Confirmar Contraseña</label></div>
                          <div class="col-12 col-md-3"><input class="form-control" type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Confirme contraseña"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row form-group">
                          <div class="col col-md-2">{{ form.groups.label }}</div>
                          <div class="col-12 col-md-3">{{ form.groups }}</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 text-center">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registrar</button>
                          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</button>
                      </div>
                  </form>
              </div>
          </div>
      {% endif %}
    </form>
{% endblock contenido %}
```

Ya se pueden ver los grupos de permisos pero no se guardan al crear los usuarios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para hacerlo tienes que indicar en `fields` que mostraras, los permisos del usuario, de la siguiente manera:

```
class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [..., 'user_permissions']
```

De esta manera en el formulario de registro podrás asignar los diferentes permisos al usuario (aunque no le encuentro sentido hacer esto).

Si quieres saber los grupos al cual fue asignado dicho usuario, agrega el campo `"groups"` a `fields`:

```
fields = [..., 'groups']
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

---

**Actualizasion 1:**

El problema del porque no se asigna el grupo o los permisos de usuario, al usuario al momento en el cual se envía el formulario, es por el form `UserCreationForm`.

El problema radica en el método `save()` del form `UserCreationForm`.

> **Código fuente del método [`save()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L133) del formulario**:
>
> ```
> def save(self, commit=True):
>     user = super().save(commit=False)
>     user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
>     if commit:
>         user.save()
>     return user
> ```

Podemos ver que llama al método `save()` del modelo mandando `commit` como `False`. Ese es el problema.

Al momento de utilizar PDB para Debuggear y encontrar que exactamente pasaba quería ver si en este punto del código estaba o no los grupos asignados al usuario:

```
117         def save(self, commit=True):
118             user = super().save(commit=False)
119  ->         user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
120             if commit:
121                 user.save()
122             return user
123  
124  
(Pdb) user.groups.all()
*** ValueError: "<User: user2@gmail.com>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Aquí fue donde todo tenia sentido, como el método `save()` del formulario `UserCreationForm` enviaba como parámetro `commit=False` no se creaba como tal el objeto o la instancia es por eso que no se existía el campo id y como consecuencia no se podía crear la relación `ManyToManyField`.

La solución seria cambiar el valor del parámetro `commit` a `True`, pero no se puede pues el método `save()` esta programado de tal manera que no lo permite. Ni utiliza el parámetro `commit` del método, directamente envía `commit` como `False` al método del modelo, por lo cual es imposible hacerlo.

Aquí cambio el parámetro `commit` a `True` con PDB en el método del modelo para asegurarme de que ese es el problema:

```
443  ->     def save(self, commit=True):
444             """
445             Save this form's self.instance object if commit=True. Otherwise, add
446             a save_m2m() method to the form which can be called after the instance
447             is saved manually at a later time. Return the model instance.
448             """
(Pdb) a
self = <UserCreationForm bound=True, valid=True, fields=(username;email;password1;password2;groups)>
commit = False
(Pdb) commit = True
(Pdb) n
> /home/lcteen/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py(449)save()
-> if self.errors:
(Pdb) n
> /home/lcteen/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py(456)save()
-> if commit:
(Pdb) n
> /home/lcteen/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py(458)save()
-> self.instance.save()
(Pdb) n
> /home/lcteen/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py(459)save()
-> self._save_m2m()
(Pdb) n
> /home/lcteen/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py(464)save()
-> return self.instance
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> /home/lcteen/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py(464)save()-><User: user4@gmail.com>
-> return self.instance
(Pdb) self.instance.groups.all()
<QuerySet [<Group: dwadawdawd>]>
```

Y funciona. Ahora la única solución es hacer que tu formulario no herede del formulario `UserCreationForm`, pues no hay manera de solucionarlo, pero la desventaja es que perderemos autenticasiones, validaciones, etc.

Otra solución es copiar directamente el formulario `UserCreationForm` y pegar en tu `forms.py`, cambiando `commit=False` por `commit=True` en el método `save()`.

Ninguna de las dos me convence. Pero no hay de otra, no hay manera de cambiar el valor de `commit` a `True` en el método `save()` de form `UserCreationForm`.

---

**Actualizasion 2:**

Por casualidad leyendo la documentación de Django sobre el método [`save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) (*ModelForms*), me encontré con que existía un método del form `ModelForm` específicamente para este problema, llamado [`_save_m2m()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L424).

Cada vez que se guarde un formulario usando `commit=False` **se genera el método `save_m2m()`**, que guarda los campos de muchos a muchos y las relaciones genéricas para este formulario.

Entonces basta con sobrescribir el método `save()` del form `UserCreationForm`, de la siguiente manera:

```
class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    ...

    def save(self, commit = True):
        user = super().save()
        self.save_m2m()
        return user
```

Y listo esta seria la solución definitiva, pues se crean las relaciones sin ningún problema.

Comment: Hola estuvo perfecta la respuesta no sabia que fuera tan sencillo, ya logro ver los grupos de permiso en el formulario pero cuando creo el usuario no se guarda con el grupo de permiso que seleccione

Comment: Si quieres añadir usuarios a grupos específicos tendrá que ser desde el admin de django.

Comment: Lo siento, estoy haciendo mi primera pregunta y aun me relaciono como funciona el foro. Pro sus comentarios entiendo entonces que para asignar usuarios a algún grupo ya creado solo se puede hacer desde el admin de django, no hay forma alguna de hacerlo desde el registro que estoy creando?

Comment: Usando los permisos me sucede lo mismo, puedo seleccionar un permiso pero cuando creo el usuario no lo guarda con el permiso que seleccione

Comment: Disculpa de nuevo, tienes razón no se guarda el grupo de usuarios. No se a que se deba esto. Voy a tratar de ver que sucede.

Comment: Ya averigüe cual es el problema, el problema es el form `UserCreationForm`, inténtalo sin heredar dicho formulario y funcionara. Estoy leyendo el código fuente del form `UserCreationForm` y no se en donde exactamente ocurre el momento en el cual no se asigna el grupo seleccionado al usuario. En el código fuente del formulario en ninguna parte se manipula grupos o permisos, no se a que se deba esto.

Comment: @RamelVitierUrquizu Actualice mi pregunta, échale un vistaso.

Comment: Genial la explicación, pero analizando la situación la verdad es que no tendría mucho sentido mostrar todos los grupos de permisos en la creación del usuario por lo que decidí mantener mi formulario pero crear una función para que cree el usuario y le asigne directamente a un grupo, por ahora eso me vale para lo que quiero y logré que lo hiciera sin problemas. Gracias por toda su ayuda.

Comment: De nada, un gusto ayudarte!!

Comment: @RamelVitierUrquizu acabo de actualizar mi respuesta con la solución definitiva, échale un vistaso :)